# Is this the correct way to initialize a game structure?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm supposed to implement a board game. The game is supposed to start with a white piece in the position (3,4) and player one will be the first one to play.

I must use the following structures:

```
typedef enum {EMPTY, WHITE, BLACK} PIECE;

typedef struct {
   int column;
   int row;
} COORDINATE;

typedef struct {
  COORDINATE player1;
  COORDINATE player2;
} PLAY;

typedef PLAY PLAYS[32];
typedef struct {
   PIECE board[8][8];
   COORDINATE last_play;
   PLAYS plays;
   int numberOfPlays;
   int current_player;
} GAME;
```

I'm supposed to create a function with the following prototype: 
`GAME *initialize_game(){`. Therefore, it has no arguments. My first thought was, correct me if I'm wrong, I can't return a pointer to an array I only define inside this function(without malloc). I did not know how to do it with my current knowledge so a google search led me to find `malloc`. I would like to know if this is is the only solution or if it's a good one, provided that this function doesn't take any arguments.
I did it as such and I would like to know if this is good:

```
GAME *initialize_game(){

   GAME* new = malloc (sizeof(game));

   PIECE brd [][8]= {{EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                 {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                 {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,WHITE,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY},
                {EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY}};

     *new = {brd,{3,4},{},0,1};

      return (new);

}
```

Comment: That's correct. A suggestion: avoid using `c++` keywords such as `new` as variable names in `c` code, even if the compiler allows it.

Comment: The assignment shouldn’t compile. You’d need to make it into a compound literal.  Also the `{}` won't compile in C.  You'll need to use something like `{ 0 }` or `{ { { 0, 0 } } }` (if I'm counting nesting right; no promises) in place of it.

Comment: _Nb_ `GAME *initialize_game()` is not a type-checkable prototype; recommend getting rid of the loud `typedefs` and use `[static] struct Game *initialize_game(void)` (for `malloc`; make sure one checks the return) or `[static] void initialize_game(struct Game *const game)` when one has a game that needs to be initialised, (I would think that matches the function name.)

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question won't compile, which is presumably why it's a question.  There are multiple problems with it, including:

- The assignment `*new = { … };` won't work; you'd need a [compound literal](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) on the right: `*new = (GAME) { … };`.
- The array initializer `{}` in the middle won't work in standard C; you need `{ { { 0 }, { 0 } } }` or thereabouts (it may depend on how stringent your compiler options are).
- You can't use the `brd` variable in the initializer like that.
- You don't check that the memory allocation succeeds.

In the code below, I show a straight-forward adptation of your code that does compile cleanly:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c game19.c 
$
```

There's also an alternative version which looks simpler to me.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum { EMPTY, WHITE, BLACK } PIECE;

typedef struct
{
    int column;
    int row;
} COORDINATE;

typedef struct
{
    COORDINATE player1;
    COORDINATE player2;
} PLAY;

typedef PLAY PLAYS[32];
typedef struct
{
    PIECE board[8][8];
    COORDINATE last_play;
    PLAYS plays;
    int numberOfPlays;
    int current_player;
} GAME;

GAME *initialize_game(void);

GAME *initialize_game(void)
{
    GAME *game = malloc(sizeof(game));
    if (game == NULL)
        return NULL;

    *game = (GAME){
        {
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, WHITE, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
            { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY }
        },
        { 3, 4 }, { { { 0 }, { 0 } } }, 0, 1
    };

    return(game);
}

GAME *alt_initialize_game(void);

GAME *alt_initialize_game(void)
{
    assert(EMPTY == 0);
    GAME *game = calloc(1, sizeof(game));

    if (game == NULL)
        return NULL;

    game->board[3][4] = WHITE;
    game->last_play = (COORDINATE){ 3, 4 };
    game->current_player = WHITE;   /* Or is it black's turn? */

    /*
    game->numberOfPlays = 1;
    game->plays[0] = (COORDINATE){ 3, 4 };
    */

    return(game);
}
```

It isn't clear whether your 'current_player' uses `WHITE` and `BLACK` (which seems like an obvious choice) or `0` and `1`.  Also, since there is a move on the board, shouldn't the number of plays be `1` and the play should be recorded in the array?

Comment: In this game, both players move the white piece in their turn. The places where the white piece has been will be marked as black. So current_player is a number, the color don't identify the players. Thank you very much for your answer. I just have one question. You did `game -> board[3][4] = white` how will the rest of the positions be equal to EMPTY? Isn't it literally empty?  I also need to draw the board according to the pieces.

Comment: Since you carefully chose the value of EMPTY to be zero, and default initialization sets things to zero,  the board is all EMPTY (aka zero) except the one square set to WHITE.  Drawing the board is out of the scope of the question (or, at least, the answer).